# How to find cause of EC2 micro instance regular read/write surge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using a micro istance on amazon ec2 and today i received an email from amazon that my i/o usage for ebs disk is over the free tier usage so he charge me for 0.20$. 
Cloudwatch say this:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c91rrs95e

What happened at 6:50 and how can i know which process give this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at 06:40 you had 4gb read from the volume.

From the screenshot I can't tell why this happened. Could this be a backup or download of large file?

You don't state what your system is doing, or what uses it so we can only guess. If you could give more information we might be able to help.

All the best,

Will

Comment: I think it is a cronjob.. but don't know how see the list of cronjob. i didn't download nothing.

Comment: Why do you think it's a cron? Have you installed any software on this server? Have you created any cron tasks? Please could you give more information - since you created the instance, what have you done with the server - software installed, scripts run etc. The more information you give the easier it will be to find the problem.

Comment: I follow this guide: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.10-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4